# How to fix could not create java virtual machine?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to install Java so I can allocate more RAM towards the technic Minecraft launcher. I had an older version of Java so I decided to uninstall that one and install a new one. After doing so I get this error:

> ```
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occured. Program will exit.
> ```

I looked all over the web for answers and only came up with older solutions that involved going into environmental setting in the control panel however those didn't work. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: What about re-installing that older version?

Comment: Which java version did you uninstall and which java version did you install? Please state the version number, the version vendor and your platform, for example: openjdk 1.8 on Windows 10.